# arranging li elements in an equal column

Tags: css

tries to create an even set of menu columns in element ul. Searching for a solution on the Internet I tried to get the intended effect, to no avail. I am very weak when it comes to css column code, so please forgive me.

I have managed to write such a code so far:

```css
ol{
  width:100%;
}

ol > li{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:calc(100% / 5);
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    
    <li>
      <span>A</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>B</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>C</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>D</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>E</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>F</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>G</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
</ol>
```

The above code arranges the columns correctly, while if the C column is larger, then there are spaces between columns A-E, B-F. How could I get the same effect as in the picture? : [show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIvfl.png) (Delete the space between the columns)

Comment: This is a little confusing. Your code lays out the columns horizontally and you're asking about removing the resulting vertical space between those columns that align vertically. But your image, that you say you want to match, lays out the columns vertically, in two page columns. Which way do you need it?

Comment: I would like to get an effect like in the picture

Comment: In that case, you'll need to contain the whole thing to constrain the total height (perhaps put the whole thing in a `div` and consider using the [CSS multi column capability](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp).

Answer (score 2):

You could use flex. Depending on your desired order you could do it like this:

```css
ol{
  width:100%;
  display:flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ol > li{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 40%;
  background:red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    
    <li>
      <span>A</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>B</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>C</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>D</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>E</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>F</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <span>G</span>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
</ol>
```

Or like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  flex-direction: column; 
  width: 40%;
  margin: 10px; 
}

ol{
  width:100%;
  display:flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row; 
}

ol .wrapper > li{
  counter-increment: listblock;  
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:red;
  margin: 10px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <li>
      <span>A</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>B</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>C</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <li>
      <span>D</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>E</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>F</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>G</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ol>
```